# How to attach PDF to email using PHP mail function

Tags: email, email-attachments, php

I am sending an email using PHP mail function, but I would like to add a specified PDF file as a file attachment to the email. How would I do that?

Here is my current code:

```
$to = "me@myemail.com";
$subject = "My message subject";
$message = "Hello,\n\nThis is sending a text only email, but I would like to add a PDF attachment if possible.";
$from = "Jane Doe <janedoe@myemail.com>";

$headers = "From:" . $from; 
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);

echo "Mail Sent!";
```

Comment: [Please follow this link to generate dynamic PDF and  send mail ][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18396714/how-to-send-email-with-pdf-attachment-using-php/22141096#22141096

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You should consider using a PHP mail library such as [PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer) which would make the procedure to send mail much simpler and better.

Here's an example of how to use PHPMailer, it's really simple!

```
<?php

require_once('../class.phpmailer.php');

$mail             = new PHPMailer(); // defaults to using php "mail()"

$body             = file_get_contents('contents.html');
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$mail->SetFrom('name@yourdomain.com', 'First Last');

$mail->AddReplyTo("name@yourdomain.com","First Last");

$address = "whoto@otherdomain.com";
$mail->AddAddress($address, "John Doe");

$mail->Subject    = "PHPMailer Test Subject via mail(), basic";

$mail->AltBody    = "To view the message, please use an HTML compatible email viewer!"; // optional, comment out and test

$mail->MsgHTML($body);

$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer.gif");      // attachment
$mail->AddAttachment("images/phpmailer_mini.gif"); // attachment

if(!$mail->Send()) {
  echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
  echo "Message sent!";
}

?>
```

An alternative to PHPMailer is http://swiftmailer.org/

Comment: what if my attachment is stored on a remote server? does anything changes or it should work ?

Comment: [AddAttachment()](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/class.phpmailer.php#L2230) does not support remote files: `Add an attachment from a path on the filesystem`

Use *file_get_contents()* in advance, @paulalexandru ...? :/

Comment: You have not answered the question. You have merely presented an alernative solution. The user required the PHP mail function to send a pdf.

Comment: + @Nebula I do not know how this is the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Simple answer: Don't do it. building a MIME email by hand is a painful business, and VERY easy to screw up.

Instead, use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com) or [Swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org). It's almost trivial to do attachments with them, and you get FAR FAR FAR better feedback in case something does blow up, v.s. the simple true/false that mail() condescends to spit out.

Answer (score 1):

To eliminate deprecation errors,

Replace

```
$body             = eregi_replace("[\]",'',$body);
```

With

```
$body             = preg_replace('/\.([^\.]*$)/i','',$body);
```

Answer (score 0):

**This code is 100% Working**
The file here is in my remote server and for sending this remote file I've used this      `$mail->addStringAttachment(file_get_contents($path), 'brochure.pdf');` and it has worked for me.
The first parameter `$path` here defines your file path where your file is stored and Second parameter `brochure.pdf` defines your file name to be in email.
Hope it helps.

```
<?php

$html="Hi";
$path = "your_file_path.pdf";

include('smtp/PHPMailerAutoload.php');
$mail = new PHPMailer(true);
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host="smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->Port=587;
$mail->SMTPSecure="tls";
$mail->SMTPAuth=true;
$mail->Username="YOUR GMAIL USERNAME";
$mail->Password="YOUR GMAIL APP PASSWORD";
$mail->SetFrom("ADD FROM MAIL");
$mail->addAddress("ADD SEND TO");
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->Subject="Sending mail with attached PDF";
$mail->Body=$html;
$mail->addStringAttachment(file_get_contents($path), 'brochure.pdf');
$mail->SMTPOptions=array('ssl'=>array(
    'verify_peer'=>false,
    'verify_peer_name'=>false,
    'allow_self_signed'=>false
    ));

if ($mail->send()) {
     echo "done";
} else {
    // $form_message = 'Message Delivery Failed, Please send again!';
}
```

?>

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please don't post code-only answers but add a little textual explanation about how and why your approach works and what makes it different from the other answers given. You can find out more at our ["How to write a good answer"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) page.