# PHP Contact Form w/ File Upload Attachment

Tags: php, file-upload, mime

I have a simple PHP contact form ([Seen Here](http://www.starcrestescrow.com/form_realproperty_sale.html)) that I want to add a file upload option to, so clients can attach an important document and mail it to me using PHP's mail function.

The form works fine on its own, but I can't seem to get the code right for uploading the attachment, storing it temporarily on the server and sending it to me as part of the e-mail. Here is the code I'm using:

```
<?php

if ($_POST['test'] != '') {
    echo 'Unfortunately, by filling out the hidden field, you have been identified as a potential spambot and your message has been terminated.';
} else {

//Validate the name:
if (!empty($_POST['name'])) {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
} else {
    echo "You forgot to enter your name.<br>";
}

//Validate the phone:
if (!empty($_POST['phone'])) {
    $phone = $_POST['phone'];
} else {
    echo "You forgot to enter your phone number.<br>";
}

//Validate the e-mail:
if (!empty($_POST['email'])) {
    $email = $_POST['email'];
} else {
    echo "You forgot to enter your e-mail.<br>";
}

//Validate the message:
if (!empty($_POST['message'])) {
    $message = $_POST['message'];
} else {
    echo "You forgot to enter a message.";
}

if (!empty($_POST['name']) && !empty($_POST['phone']) && !empty($_POST['email']) && !empty($_POST['message'])) {

    // Obtain file upload variables:
    $attachment = $_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']; 
    $attachment_type = $_FILES['attachment']['type']; 
    $attachment_name = $_FILES['attachment']['name'];

    if (file($attachment)) { 
    // Read the file to be attached ('rb' = read binary):
    $file = fopen($attachment,'rb'); 
    $data = fread($file,filesize($attachment)); 
    fclose($file);

    // Generate a boundary string:
    $semi_rand = md5(time()); 
    $mime_boundary = "==Multipart_Boundary_x{$semi_rand}x"; 

    // Add the headers for a file attachment:
    $headers = "\nMIME-Version: 1.0\n" . 
    "Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\n" . 
    " boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";

    // Add a multipart boundary above the plain message:
    $message = "This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n\n" . 
    "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . 
    "Content-Type: text/plain; charset=\"iso-8859-1\"\n" . 
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit\n\n" . 
    $message . "\n\n";

    // Base64 encode the file data:
    $data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));  

    // Add file attachment to the message:
    $message .= "--{$mime_boundary}\n" . 
    "Content-Type: {$attachment_type};\n" . 
    " name=\"{$attachment_name}\"\n" . 
    //"Content-Disposition: attachment;\n" . 
    //" filename=\"{$attachment_name}\"\n" . 
    "Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n\n" . 
    $data . "\n\n" . 
    "--{$mime_boundary}--\n"; 
    }  

    $body = "$name\n$phone\n$email\n\n$message";
    mail("*@*.com", "Starcrest Escrow, Inc. Website - Real Property Sale", $body, $headers);
    header("Location: confirm.html");
}

}

?>
```

When I run this script presently, it forwards me to the confirmation page, but no e-mail appears to be generated at all.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Are you receiving any server errors? Is $data being filled with the contents of the attachment?

Comment: I realized that I was not pointing to the correct script in my HTML form - whoops!  Now that that's been fixed, it sends the e-mail with all of the info.  However, the attachment is displayed as text data at the bottom of the message.  A PDF file, for example, becomes lots of lines of "JVBERi0xLjMKJcfsj6IKNSAwIG9iago8PC9MZW5ndGggNiAwIFIvRmlsdGVyIC9GbGF0ZURlY29k".  Any idea what's happening?  Thanks!

Comment: yes! This is happening: `$file = fopen($attachment,'rb');` &  `$data = chunk_split(base64_encode($data));`

Comment: I apologize for being so dense, but why are those lines causing it to display as such rather than a PDF attachment? Am I missing an important step in the code?

Comment: Don't try to build MIME attachments yourself...it's complicated business: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10606558/how-to-attach-pdf-to-email-using-php-mail-function

Comment: So that's that, then, huh?  Thank you for taking the time to look things over, at least.  Much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST['txtEmail'])) {

    // EDIT THE 2 LINES BELOW AS REQUIRED

    $email_to = "xyz@abc.com";
    $email_subject = "Subject";
    $email_from = "abc@xyz.com";
    function died($error)
    {

        // your error code can go here

        echo "We are very sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
        echo "These errors appear below.";
        echo $error . "<br /><br />";
        echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
        die();
    }

    // validation expected data exists

    if (!isset($_POST['txtName']) || !isset($_POST['txtEmail']) || !isset($_POST['txtAddress']) || !isset($_POST['txtContact']) || !isset($_POST['txtUpload'])) {
        died('We are sorry, but there appears to be a problem with the form you submitted.');
    }

    $name = $_POST['txtName']; // required
    $email = $_POST['txtEmail']; // required
    $address = $_POST['txtAddress']; // required
    $contact = $_POST['txtContact']; // not required
    $upload = $_POST['txtUpload']; // required
    $email_message = "Form Details are below.\n\n";
    function clean_string($string)
    {
        $bad = array(
            "content-type",
            "bcc:",
            "to:",
            "cc:",
            "href"
        );
        return str_replace($bad, "", $string);
    }

    $email_message.= "Full Name: " . clean_string($name) . "\n\n";
    $email_message.= "Address: " . clean_string($address) . "\n\n";
    $email_message.= "Email ID: " . clean_string($email) . "\n\n";
    $email_message.= "Contact No.: " . clean_string($contact) . "\n\n";
    $email_message.= "File: " . clean_string($upload) . "\n\n";

    // create email headers

    $headers = 'From: ' . $email_from . "\r\n" . 'Reply-To: ' . $email . "\r\n" . 'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
    @mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
?>
    <!-- include your own success html here -->

    Thank you for contacting us. We will be in touch with you very soon.

    <?php
}

?>
```

Comment: ...are you asking how to add this code to the OP's question??

Comment: The batsticks are used for short pieces of code, and four spaces for multiline, see http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help. But read the guide [answer] **too** ;) (basically: explain your code and mention the source if you copied it from somewhere)